# Laravel API with JWT authentication: Auth facade returns ID but 'ID does not exist' error occurs when inserting into database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm encountering a peculiar problem with Laravel involving a protected API that requires authentication. The system retrieves the user ID via the auth facade when a request is made with a JWT key. However, an error occurs when attempting to insert the ID into the database, stating that it does not exist.

I'm unable to reproduce the error in my local environment. Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.